# Passing thru Password field to run( sys.executable) error on run

Tags: python-3.x, django, unicode, passwords, ldap3

on command:
On conn bind pass true

```
        ldap3.extend.microsoft.modifyPassword.
        ad_modify_password(conn, dn, password, old_password=None)
```

On View.py

```
        scriptFile = 'support01\\ldap_cmd.py'
            base_dir = settings.BASE_DIR
            config_path = os.path.join(base_dir, scriptFile)
            run([sys.executable, config_path, 
        current_user.username, var_selfpassword,var_Usernameset,var_Setpassword])
```

Error when executing.

```
> conn = Connection(Server('ldaps://xxxx.xxxx.local', port=636,
> use_ssl=True),
>         File "C:\perforce_workspace\Python\support01\
>         venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", 
>         line 363, in __init__self._do_auto_bind()
>         File "C:\perforce_workspace\Python\support01\
>         venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 389, in _do_auto_bind
>         self.bind(read_server_info=True)
>         File "C:\perforce_workspace\Python\support01\
>         venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 604, in bind
>         request = bind_operation(self.version, self.authentication,
>         self.user, self.password, auto_encode=self.auto_encode)
>         File "C:\perforce_workspace\Python\support01
>         \venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\operation\bind.py", line 57, in bind_operation
>         request['authentication'] = AuthenticationChoice().
>         setComponentByName('simple', Simple(validate_simple_password(password)))
>         File "C:\perforce_workspace\Python\support01\
>         venv\lib\site-packages\ldap3\protocol\sasl\sasl.py",
>         line 136, in validate_simple_password
>         password = sasl_prep(password)
>         File "C:\perforce_workspace\Python\support01\venv
>         \lib\site-packages\ldap3\protocol\sasl\sasl.py", line 53, in sasl_prep
>         if stringprep.in_table_c12(c):
>         File "C:\Users\#######\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
>         lib\stringprep.py", line 211, in in_table_c12
>         return unicodedata.category(code) == "Zs" and code != " "
>         TypeError: category() argument must be a unicode character, not str
```

Comment: Adding a Django Password field and passing the variable into sys.argv to run the Executable.  Not sure why this happen even in bind using  var_selfpassword = form.cleaned_data['selfpassword']   class PasswordField(forms.Form):
    selfpassword = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    Usernameset = forms.CharField(max_length=7)
    Setpassword = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        fields = ['selfpassword', 'Usernameset', 'Setpassword']

Comment: current_user = request.user      bind user is current_user.username  and selfpassword field.